# Difference in implementation of datatype& const var_name in Visual Studio and others

Tags: c++, constants

```
void function(int & const a){
  a=4;
}
```

The above snippet works fine in Visual Studio but fails in DevC++ and other IDEs ,

error msg : `'const' qualifiers cannot be applied to 'int&'`

It makes sense that we are initializing constant pointer to an int. If we need to mention the value to constant pointer while initializing it still doesn't work but works fine in Visual Studio

```
main(){
  int a=10;
  int & const p_a=&a; //works in Visual Studio
  cout<<p_a<<endl;
}
```

Explanation regarding the constraint and way to resolve it would be helpful

Comment: It's not pointer, but reference.

Comment: If you are looking to pass an argument by reference to const it should be `fn(const int& p)` instead. Your compiler will probably issue a *C4227 anachronism used* warning.

Comment: I wanted the pointer to be constant and the value to be modifiable

Comment: @rainversion_3 there are no pointer variables in your code

Comment: "I wanted the pointer to be constant and the value to be modifiable" Then it should be `int * const a`.

Comment: ok .. I got where I am going wrong but what does `int & const a` mean and why am I not getting error in Visual Studio

Comment: @rainversion_3 I answered the 1st part of your question; about the VS part, I'm not sure but it seems a bug.

Comment: @rainversion_3 it doesn't really mean anything, since you can't change a reference (as in, you can't change what it refers to), a reference is always const in a certain sense. In another way they're never const since references aren't 'objects' in the c++ sense of the word but merely an alias to an actual 'object'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int & const` is not valid syntax, `int&` is a reference (to `int`), which can't be qualified by `const`. More precisely, you can't declare a const reference. On the other hand, declaring reference to `const` (i.e. `const int &`) is fine.

> I wanted the pointer to be constant and the value to be modifiable

What you want is *pointer*, so it should be `int * const` (i.e. const pointer to non-const `int`).